# For loop with different variables python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Lets say I have three arrays :

```
listXYZ = ['X','Y', 'Z']
list123 = ['1','2','3']
listLetter= ['FF','GG','ZZ']
```

I tried:

```
for list,x,y in listXYZ,list123,listLetter:
print(list,x,y)
```

and I'm getting output `x,y,z 1,2,3` etc . What i want is for it to print `X 1 FF, Y 2 GG` etc.
How do I do that ?

Comment: use `zip`, `for lst,x,y in zip(listXYZ,list123,listLetter):` and don't use built-in function as variables, `list` is an built-in function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip()` like so:

```
for x, y, z in zip(listXYZ,list123,listLetter):
    print(x, y, z)
```

Also please don't use builtin names as variable names.